# merge 2 Oracle queries into one with some generic data specified with null

Tags: oracle, isnull

Can I write one Oracle query that can do something like that?
if code is XXX, then return V1,V2
if code is not XXX, then return those values whose code = null, i.e. V3, V4

Table1

```
code value
---- -----
XXX V1
XXX V2
null    V3
null    V4
```

I need to write something like that:

- select * from Table1 where code = 'XXX'
- if no rows return, run the follow query
- select * from Table1 where code is null

Comment: please be a bit more specific. For example: Are V1,V2 tables or columns?

Comment: You want a query for a key-value table, with a fallback if the key does not exist, to key=null. You should rewrite your question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I completely follow what you are looking for.  You could implement your bullet points with something like

```
select *
  from table1 t1
 where t1.code = 'XXX'
union all
select *
  from table1 t1_2
 where t1_2.code is null
   and not exists( select 1
                     from table1 t1_3
                    where t1_3.code = 'XXX' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with q as
 (select code, value from table1 where code = 'XXX')
select *
  from q
union all
select code, value
  from table1
 where code is null and not exists (select 1 from q)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used dbfiddle.uk for testing only but I think this would work. Just remove the "with table1 as" clause as it is used for building up the data for testing.

```
with table1 as
(
select 'XXX' as code, 'V1' as value from dual
union
select 'XXX' as code, 'V2' as value from dual
union
select null as code, 'V3' as value from dual
union
select null as code, 'V4' as value from dual
)
select *
from table1
where nvl(code, '!!!') = 'XXX'
union 
select *
from table1
where code is null
and not exists(select 1 from table1 where code='XXX')
```